# Partial derivative of trig function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I need some assistance on the following calculus problem:

Let

$$w = 2\cot(x)+y^2z^2$$
$$x = uv$$
$$y = \sin(uv)$$
$$z = e^u$$

Find $\frac{\partial w}{\partial u}$ for $u = \frac{1}{4}$ and $v = \pi$.

I realise they're asking for a partial derivative here, and they are looking to substitute expressions based on the notation given.  However, I'm concerned with the order that I should begin differentiating - any suggestions with how I should start a problem like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $y=\sin x$ and $z^2=e^{2u}$

$\therefore w=2\cot (uv)+y^2z^2=2\cot(uv)+\sin^2 (uv)e^{2u}$

$\therefore \dfrac{\partial w}{\partial u}=\sin(uv)(e^{2u}v\cot(uv)-v\csc^4(uv)+e^{2u})$

$\left[\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial u}\right]_{v=\pi,u=\frac{1}{4}}=\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{4})\left(e^{\frac{1}{2}}\cot(\dfrac{\pi}{4})-v\csc^4(\dfrac{\pi}{4})+e^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$

Compute the values and get the answer. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

The (multi-variable) chain rule here gives
$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}$$
You should be able to sort this out and plug in your values.